# Create Function Parameter Accept Wild Cards

Tags: powershell

I have a function that I am writing and I would like to create a wild card process on the WMI call. Wondering what my options might be. My first thought was to take the parameter value sent and replace any asterisk with percent signs and have a case statement that will use a query string depending on if I need to use a `LIKE` statement or not. Am I over complicating it and is there a much simpler way I have not found?

Here is the top portion of the function as it so

```
[CmdletBinding()]    
Param(
[Parameter(Mandatory=$false,ValueFromPipeline=$true,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$True)][string]$Name = "",
[Parameter(Mandatory=$false,ValueFromPipeline=$true,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$True)][string]$ComputerName = $env:ComputerName,
[Parameter()][string]$Port = "",
[Parameter()][switch]$Full
)

Process {
 if($ComputerName.Trim()) {
    try {
    $printers = (Get-WmiObject -Query "select * from Win32_printer where portname like '%$port%' and name like '%$Name%' " -ComputerName $ComputerName -EnableAllPrivileges -ErrorAction Stop)
```

This is kind of what I was trying to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

We clear the clutter for this function to show the bare minimum needed to prove our point. `Like`'s strong point is using wildcards however the comparison will still function without them. Only caveat is that the *could* be a performance issue and that `=` would be better. Point being is that, for simplicity sake at least, we are going to optionally add the wildcards to the query string.

```
Function Get-Printers{
[CmdletBinding()]    
Param(
    [Parameter()][string]$Name = "",
    [Parameter()][string]$Port = "",
    [Parameter()][switch]$Wild = $True
)
    $wildcard = if($wild){"%"}Else{$null}
    Get-WmiObject -Query ("select * from Win32_printer where portname like '{0}$port{0}' and name like '{0}$Name{0}'" -f $wildcard)
}
```

So by default the function will use wildcards. In the query string we use the format operator to add in whatever the `$wildcard` was determined to be. So if the `-Wild` was `true` then the query would look like this:

```
select * from Win32_printer where portname like '%Fax%' and name like '%Fax%'
```

Else, if it was false then they same query would look like this:

```
select * from Win32_printer where portname like 'Fax' and name like 'Fax'
```

To reiterate, with the latter query in mind, the use of `like` without wildcards will produce the same results as if we just had `=`.

Comment: Thanks @Matt for the Edit and the Answer. How would you use your format method to direct a positional based wild card, ie 'Fax%' vs. '%Fax%'. I think I found a pretty simple way thru your comment of the like statement also treating the search as an equal to some extent when % is not present and will post.

Comment: @ssaviers The simplest thing would be to have a string with ValidateSet and have Wild be `[ValidateSet("On", "Off", "Prefix", "Suffix")]`. Then using a switch statement so can conditionally set the presence of wildcards.

Answer (score 0):

With Matts reference I found that this seems to work as well. I was trying to get all crazy before with a case statement and checking the value passed via `$name[0]` and `$name[-1]` to see what position the wild card value was to define the particular case statement to run not thinking that the like statement doesn't really care.

```
Function Get-Printers{
[CmdletBinding()]    
Param(
    [Parameter()][string]$Name = "*",
    [Parameter()][string]$Port = "*"
)
    $Name = $Name.Replace('*','%')
    $Port = $Port.Replace('*','%')

    Get-WmiObject -Query ("select * from Win32_printer where portname like '$port' and name like '$Name'")
}
```

Thanks Matt!